# Trying to get Camera Display name crashes activity page

Tags: dji-sdk

Since the FPVwidget and FPVOverLayWidget do no carry over settings and OSD correctly for the Zenmuse XT Im trying to make a settings activity to where I can change some of the basic settings. These setting I do not want enabled if the Zenmuse XT is not connected. So I have been writing some test code to check functionality and the settings activity keeps crashing with an error from logcat saying:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String dji.sdk.camera.Camera.getDisplayName()' on a null
>   object reference

Here is my code:

```js
thermalColorPalletSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.thermalColorPalletSwitch);

        if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera().getDisplayName().equals(Camera.DisplayNameXT)){

            thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(false);

        }else{

            thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(false);

        }
```

I have also tried this code with the same results:

```js
        thermalColorPalletSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.thermalColorPalletSwitch);

        if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera() != null){
            if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera().getDisplayName().equals(Camera.DisplayNameXT)){
                
                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(true);
                
            }else{

                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure what Im doing wrong.

I also tried the following code which works as intended when swapping between the Zenmuse X3 and Zenmuse XT on my Inspire 1. However if the App does not have a connection to the remote controller the settings activity still crashes.

```js
thermalColorPalletSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.thermalColorPalletSwitch);

        if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera() != null){

            if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera().isThermalCamera()){

                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(true);
                
            }else{
                
                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So aparently you have to check to see if there is even a connection to a DJI product before you even start to check to see if there is any information about the cameras.

This code works with no crashes.

```js
 thermalColorPalletSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.thermalColorPalletSwitch);

        if(null != FPVApplication.getProductInstance() && FPVApplication.getProductInstance().isConnected()){

            if(FPVApplication.getProductInstance().getCamera().isThermalCamera()){

                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(true);

            }else{

                thermalColorPalletSwitch.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```